# can I bypass screen lock request to log in to google (Samsung Galaxy S)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, lock-screens, password

My two year old kept getting into my phone, so I put a pattern lock on it.  She played with this too many times and the screen is now locked, which shouldn't be a problem as it has just asked me to log into my google account to get past it, but it isn't accepting my google password for some reason.  I've spoken to people at Samsung and Vodafone who say I need to take my phone in to a technician.  I'm pretty sure they will just wipe it clean and make me start over.  I'd rather not do this, and even if I have to I'll have to go to another city to do it, which is a pain.  Does anyone know how to get past this password request since it isn't working?

Comment: I take it you've already tried pulling the battery?  Also, can you login to your google account on your computer?

Answer (score 6):

Try logging into your Google account on your computer and changing the password to something very simple like "123456".  Then try it on your phone again.  I had a problem once logging into my Nook account on my Droid so I logged into the website and changed my password from the standard complex string of random numbers and characters to a plain string, and it let me in.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried recovering your Google password? https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery

Note: this may be worthless if you never set up a secondary email account to recover your google account.  Because there is no other way to recover a Google password.

Comment: They also have a secret question option.  I don't have a secondary email on one of my gmail accounts and I've been allowed to change the password by answering my secret question.

Comment: @Matt Ah thanks, I forgot about the secret question.  Either way, if you don't remember the secret q&a or don't have a secondary email, you may be out of luck.